# How to figure out which directory is web server root?

Tags: apache-http-server, webserver, localhost, httpd, http-status-code-404

I want to view websites hosted on my Mac when running Windows VMware Fusion.

I have an entry in the Windows `hosts` file to enable the routing:

```
#ip of my mac   domain i use on the VM to access it
192.168.1.70    mymac
```

However, it resolves to an empty directory as a 404 is generated. I can see the access log on my Mac that everything is OK access wise. Firefox on VMware states the following response headers:

```
Server    Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l DAV/2 PHP/5.3.1
```

Any ideas how I can figure out what directory is being served? I am lost in a maze of twisty httpd.conf passages.

The access log, unfortunately, just lists / as the root dir being served

localhost on my Mac resolves to my ~/Sites directory.
192.168.1.70 resolves to the same empty directory/404.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The only "passages" you need to worry about are the declarations that start with `DocumentRoot`. There should be one global declaration and one for each VirtualHost you might have setup.

Comment: Thanks!

I went through and checked all of my Virtual Hosts. there was an entry for a project I no longer have a directory for, I thought I had deleted the entry.

So, now it routes to the first VH in my list. A different problem, but progress non the less.

Comment: The solution for it pointing to the first VH in my list was that I needed to use the same "URL" in the windows hosts file as is set on my Mac. In this example mymac in Windows host will look for Virtualhost of the same name on my Mac setup. Sorted!

Answer (score 0):

First off tell us what exactly you're using as a web server. If you're using the built-in Apache server (instead of say [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html)), it will be whatever you set it to in the System Preferences.

Second, try placing various `index.html` files around the place. Place one in `/` and see if it gets served. If it does then you will have found where it's serving files from.

Have you tried simply typing `http://192.168.1.70/` in the VMWare window?

Comment: I am using Apache 2 built-in.

I wanted a more exact method not just a wild goose chase with index.html

http://192.168.1.70/ in the VM lead to the same 404